# How can I turn off my view of deleted stuff?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-posts

**"I can see dead people"**

I've recently acquired 'access to moderator tools', and, as a result (I think), I now get to see things that have been deleted.

I realise that with great power comes great responsibility, and I may even have an *obligation* to look at these things, but I would prefer not to. So, two questions in one:

- Is it possible to suppress my view of deleted stuff?
- Is it ethical for me to do so?

Comment: [Please catch me](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/65683/top-investors).

Comment: btw, this just shows that "priviledges" might not be the right word ;)

Comment: +1 for the "dead people"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These posts are [forced-visible to all 10k users all the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33122/deleting-comments-not-by-me-on-my-answer/33142#33142) and this is by design.

I think it is better to see this as a matter of being encouraged, rather than being responsible.  You can always give away the reputation in a bonfire of bounties.

Comment: Interesting strategy.

Answer (score 15):

There is no option provided by SX to hide these posts, but: Deleted posts have a different look, so they need to have different CSS classes. It is therefore possible to write a user script which changes the corresponding CSS style to hide these posts or even replaces them with a short notice. I programmed something like this once for a forum where you couldn't blacklist posts by certain users.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I have been known to do CSS stuff in the past, but it's just one more thing to maintain, so I guess I'll just have to grin and bear it...

Comment: That is a brilliant suggestion, all I had to do is added `.deleted-answer {display: none;}` to may CSS and the scary red boxes are gone!

Comment: @KhaledHosny However, this is an abuse of SE's intention, as explained in Chalres' answer.

Comment: @KhaledHosny How do you inject that? Greasemonkey?

Comment: @tohecz: that does not change the fact that they scare me and make my user experience less pleasent, I can go and spend points on pounties but hiding them is much less work and more sustainable `:)` Brent.Longborough: http://userstyles.org/ (using Stylish for Firefox)

Comment: For Chrome the extension [Personalized Web](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personalized-web/plcnnpdmhobdfbponjpedobekiogmbco) does a decent job.

Answer (score 12):

We could all downvote you back below 10k, that would work I think. Or you could give me a 500 bounty for something.

Comment: Looks like the bounty solution only works for `vi` users.