# For how long a removed answer is shown?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-posts

I ''answered'' a question, but later in a comment i watched that it wasn't the response expected by user (it didn't answer the original question). I'm sorry, that was an error. I click in **delete**  but after of 2 days this answer even appears (highlighted with the **undelete** option).

I really believe that this answer confuses to other users (and to me, although they do not see it) and i'd like that it disappears definitely.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

Your post has been deleted. It is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) that authors of questions/answers [can always see their own posts, even if they have deleted them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion/177675#177675).

Moreover, users with access to the moderator tools (*i.e.*, moderators and [users with ≥ 10,000 reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)) can also see any deleted posts. (See also [How can I turn off my view of deleted stuff?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3267/how-can-i-turn-off-my-view-of-deleted-stuff))

However, to everyone except yourself and except those with access to the moderator tools, the post will not be visible—that is, it really has been deleted, even though you can still see it.

Comment: Indeed, we tend to say 'removed from public view' for this reason.

Comment: If there was a petition to change the name to 'remove from public view', I'd sign it.

Comment: @1010011010 I would not. We all know that _nothing_ is actually deleted on the internet. "Removed form public view" is just too complicated. I would tend to better say "marked as deleted".

Comment: @tohecz: One could also say 'hidden' ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hidden sounds like a hidden feature: something that you want to see but you're not a VIP (or you didn't pay enough for subscription) so you can't see it ...